# Что необходимо изменить в скобочной последовательности [((())()(())]], чтобы она стала правильной?

Tags: java

Что необходимо изменить в данной скобочной последовательности с точки зрения Java, чтобы она стала правильной?

Пробовал всевозможными способами с помощью интерпретатора repl.it проверить верность тех или иных манипуляций с удалением, на мой взгляд, неверных скобок, но каждый раз интерпретатор выдает некорректный вывод по ошибкам, например, как здесь:

```
Main.java:3: error: illegal start of expression
    System.out.println([((())()(())]); 
                       ^
Main.java:3: error: -> expected
    System.out.println([((())()(())]); 
                            ^
Main.java:3: error: ')' expected
    System.out.println([((())()(())]); 
                             ^
3 errors
exit status 1
```

Comment: Какой интерпретатор в джаве?  Компилятор не в состоянии разобрать, что вы хотите впихнуть в качестве аргумента метода `PrintStream::println`, и выдает массу ошибок для Java-кода.  То есть, _с точки зрения Java_ приведённые скобочные последовательности вполне бессмысленны.  Вам ведь нужно проверить сбалансированность скобок в некой строке?

Comment: Если простыми словами, то да, мне необходимо понять, как привести данную скобочную последовательность к правильному виду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, проведя небольшой рессерч, я нашёл занятный [видос на ютубе](https://youtu.be/lNi59Um0_rA), где рассматривается алгоритмизированный подход в решении задачек на правильную скобочную последовательность, и в нем вводится такое понятие, как стек (stack), в котором мы, при движении по строке слева направо, «кладём» каждую открывающую скобку, и «забираем» по одной открывающей скобке, если нам по ходу движения по строке встречаются закрывающие скобки.

Таким образом, правильная скобочная последовательность для указанной последовательности выше, будет выглядеть так: [((()))(())].

Надеюсь, кому-нибудь это будет полезно.

Answer (score 3):

Если вам надо из неправильной последовательности получить любую правильную удалением / добавлением скобок и при этом у вас только 1 вид скобок `()`, то вам не нужнен стек, это делается простым счетчиком.

Идея алгоритма в том, чтобы при проходе по строке, считать сколько незакрытых скобок в момент и не допускать закрытых скобок без парных открытых, а в конце закрыть все незакрытое. То есть по сути, этот алгоритм закроет все незакрытые скобки и удалит закрывающие скобки без парных открывающих. Пример

```
private static String getValidParentheses(String input) {
    int open = 0;
    int ind = 0;

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    while (ind < input.length()) {
        char c = input.charAt(ind);
        if (c == '(') {
            open++;
            result.append(c);
        }
        if (c == ')' && open > 0) {
            open--;
            result.append(c);
        }
        ind++;
    }
    while (open > 0) {
        result.append(')');
        open--;
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Проверка

```
System.out.println(getValidParentheses("((())()(())"));
System.out.println(getValidParentheses("(((()"));
System.out.println(getValidParentheses("())))"));
```

Вывод

```
((())()(()))
(((())))
()
```

Конкретно этот алгоритм самый простой, но если добавить сюда другие типы скобок, то придется да, пользоваться стеком, что тоже не проблема, если вас устроит любое количество изменений в строке.